# Making background page accessible while opening thickbox pop up(JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, thickbox

I'm trying to create a pop up page in asp.net, which when clicked from another aspx page...opens up as a 'modal dialog' style (in an iframe). I thought i could use the "thick box" J Query plugin to make that happen, but one of my requirements is that the background page should be 'accessible' while the pop up is opened. 
 also need to make the pop up drag-gable.
I have the Pop up web page in a new aspx file. I am trying to open up the pop up aspx page using the "thick box' plugin.(Which puts the Popup in an 'iframe' of specified width and height) but I cant figure out how to make the "background' page accessible? Any thoughts/inputs??

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My team opted to use ColorBox, which is a jQuery plug-in. It can use an iFrame, but I ran into the same issue you did. Specifically, I needed a modal popup window when a user logged in to our site. I needed to do a page transfer and have access to common code which was made impossible using an iFrame. My solution was to use the modal popup window control from the Microsoft AJAX Toolkit. It solved my problem of having access to common code and it was able to use an update panel to mimic ajax calls. I would suggest giving it a try in a demo project and see how that goes.